# .NET RSA.Create(String algName): What goes in algName?

Tags: .net, cryptography, rsa

According to the MSDN documentation for the RSA class there are two [RSA.Create() methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsa.create.aspx). One default implementation and one that takes a string parameter "algName". I haven't been able to find any examples using the RSA.Create(String) version anywhere online.

So my questions are: What does the parameter "algName" usually contain? What are a few algorithms that can be used? Or where can I find for information on valid algorithm names?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can put anything you like, but I think you need to implement it yourself. There is only one implementation of the `RSA` algorithm in the .NET framework out-of-the-box, namely `RSACryptoServiceProvider`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx

The `Create(String)` method is inherited from `AsymmetricAlgorithm`, and you can pass quite a few values to the method, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf2t8ayw.aspx for a complete list...

Answer (score 5):

The various Create methods of the .NET cryptographic API are meant to work with **machine.config** file and the System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig type.

It allows an application that use them to use the machine configured algorithm implementation (hence the use of **machine.config**). E.g.

```
RSA rsa = RSA.Create ();
```

will create, by default (nothing in machine.config), a RSACryptoServiceProvider. Now if you modify machine.config your application could return to you a RSAManaged instance (e.g. by configuring it to use Mono.Security.dll). This is very useful to allow applications to select specific implementations (e.g. FIPS-140 certifiied) or HSM (hardware security modules) - i.e. no need to recompile your application to support them!

Back to the original **Create(string)**, this method let you select which implementation to use. It simply call CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(string) and cast the result back to, in this case, an **RSA** instance.

This is useful if you want to be **sure** to use a specific implementation, e.g. RSAManaged - even without linking your application to a specific assembly (e.g. Mono.Security.dll).

Answer (score 2):

Erik A. Brandstadmoen answer was correct up until now, but with .NET 4.6 there is a 2nd RSA class now:

RSACng

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacng(v=vs.110).aspx

RSA.Create() still returns the RSACryptoServiceProvider by default, but as mentioned above you can change this behaviour in the machine.config.

If you are interested in a more in detail comparison and examples how to override it in machine.config you can check out this blog post:

http://dusted.codes/how-to-use-rsa-in-dotnet-rsacryptoserviceprovider-vs-rsacng-and-good-practise-patterns